# How to Pass an object of VB Structure to VC++ dll structure?

Tags: c++, vb.net, oop

------------------------------------VB Code------------------------------------

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Structure Test_Structure
        Dim xyz As Integer
        Dim abc As System.String
    End Structure 

    Dim OBJ_Structure As New Test_Structure
    Dim OBJ_Dll As New Test_Dll

    Public Sub Temp()
        OBJ_Dll.Dll_Function(OBJ_Structure) 
    End Sub
End Class
```

--------------------------------VC++ Code------------------------------------

```
Public ref Class Dll
{
    public ref struct Temp
    {
        int xyz;
        System::String^ abc;
    };

    int Dll_Function(Temp^ obj_Temp);
};
```

As Shown above, I want to pass object of VB Structure(unmanaged) into VC++ Structure(managed). But I get error of type-conversion. What should be solution of this.

Comment: That is not C++ code and it isn't unmanaged.  You are doing it wrong, there must be only **one** definition of the structure.  Delete Test_Structure from your VB code and use Temp from your C++/CLI assembly.  Give it a better name.

Comment: If I delete Structure from VB than how can I get value from VB to VC++?